# AutoKeras: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, auto-keras

Getting error in Autkeras model, where as same data work in keras model

### Dataset example

```
image                  label
train/class0/3.jpg      0
train/class1/2.jpg      1
train/class1/6.jpg      1
train/class1/4.jpg      1
train/class0/7.jpg      0
```

### load function

```
def load(image_path,label):
  img = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  #img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
  img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 255.0
  label = tf.cast(label, tf.int32)
  return img, label
```

load data

```
 bs=2
 train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_df.image,train_df.label)).map(load).batch(bs)
```

### keras model

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.InputLayer((224,224,3)),                         
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
])
```

train keras model

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_ds,epochs=1)
```

### AutoKeras model

```
import autokeras as ak
clf = ak.ImageClassifier(overwrite=False, max_trials=1)
clf.fit(train_ds, epochs=1)
```

Error log in autokeras model

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 104, in build
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 64, in _build_wrapper
    return self._build(hp, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/autokeras/graph.py", line 250, in build
    outputs = block.build(hp, inputs=temp_inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/autokeras/engine/block.py", line 38, in _build_wrapper
    return super()._build_wrapper(hp, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 64, in _build_wrapper
    return self._build(hp, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/autokeras/blocks/wrapper.py", line 108, in build
    output_node = self._build_block(hp, output_node, block_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/autokeras/blocks/wrapper.py", line 77, in _build_block
    return basic.ResNetBlock().build(hp, output_node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/autokeras/engine/block.py", line 38, in _build_wrapper
    return super()._build_wrapper(hp, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 64, in _build_wrapper
    return self._build(hp, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/autokeras/blocks/basic.py", line 688, in build
    if input_node.shape[1] < min_size or input_node.shape[2] < min_size:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: is the Keras model working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Too short to be real answer but. If you chek `train_ds.element_spec` you will see something like `[None,None,3]` or even `[None,None,None]`.
In first case only thing you need to do is to resize image with `img = tf.image.resize(img, [128, 128])`
In second case you allso need to set channels on `decode_<img>` (i see that you allready set this)

Example used with loading from disk (tested to work with autokeras)

```py
def process_path(filename):
    parts = tf.strings.split(filename, os.sep)
    label = int(parts[-2])

    image = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.io.decode_png(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [256, 256])
    return image, label

import pathlib
load_from = pathlib.Path(load_from)
train_files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(load_from / 'train' / '*/*.png'))
train_ds: tf.data.Dataset = train_files_ds.map(process_path)

import autokeras as ak
clf = ak.ImageClassifier(overwrite=False, max_trials=1)
clf.fit(train_ds, epochs=1)
```

Comment: As i'v found - this does-not work (it just launches learning pipeline but for real mdel learns nothing). But `ak.image_dataset_from_directory` - works.
I dont know why. Mainly they are doing resize+reshape. no other changes i'v found.